# Does Gmail have a problem sending to emails with dashes in them?

Tags: gmail, special-characters

Gmail keeps hanging on me sending an email to `kindle-feedback@amazon.com`.

Does Gmail not like dashes in the "To:" field?

**EDIT:** In this case I finally got it to send when I opened the email to a large window, but I'd still like to know what's up.  There's mention of punctuation causing problems in Gmail help, but no solutions (or even acknowledgement).

Comment: I am having the exact same problem right now! Google is refusing to accept/send an email that has dashes. It has happened before and I do think it is specific to gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dashes are valid in e-mail addresses.

It is very, very unlikely that it's the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly post to mailing lists that have dashes in the name and have never had a problem. I've used both IE8 and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be cache issue? Try to clear your browser's cache and see whether you still have the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

This would not be an issue for sending email *from* a Gmail account but if you're trying to send email *to* a Gmail account, including dashes in the email address will make it invalid.

For instance, if my email address is `bob@gmail.com`, attempting to send an email `b-ob@gmail.com` will result in an `Address not found` response.

**Note:** Such is not the case with other characters like `.`, which can be included anywhere (e.g. `b.o.b@gmail.com`) or `+` which can be included at the end (e.g. `bob+hello@gmail.com`).